# Keep tab open in Xcode 12's new tab interface

Tags: macos, tabs, xcode

The new tab interface in Xcode 12 italicizes tabs that don't stay open as seen as you open another file. I was wondering whether there is a keyboard shortcut to keep a tab open.

If you right click the italicized tab you can keep it open by selecting the menu option.

[image: Right click menu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're on the active tab you can press: Command + Option + O

Or depending on your navigation settings in Xcode, you can just double-click the file from project navigator.

Comment: You can also double-click the tab itself.